# token0() and token1() functions in IUniswapV2Pair.sol

Tags: solidity

I was looking into the interface and found these two functions. When checking the UniswapV2Pair.sol contract I couldn't find those functions. Any idea where to find those functions and how do they work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are implicitely created as both `token0` and `token1` are `public` attributes of `UniswapV2Pair` as you can see [here](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol#L19).

The [IUniswapV2Pair](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol#L38) interface is just explicitly mentioning [the auto generated getters](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/contracts.html?highlight=getters#state-variable-visibility) for `token0` and `token1` as they can be useful.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks it does answer the question, on the other hand is there another way to determine token0 and token1 from the pair address? say we got the pair address of WETH and USDT, how do we determine how the tokens are sorted in that pair, is it by reserves or address?

Comment: It's by address as you can see here (https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol#L25). The lowest address between `tokenA` and `tokenB` will be `token0`, the other one is `token1`.